# pandas dataframe row shows entire string instead of it being truncated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is outputting the length of the entire string/list in jupyter which is not the intended outcome.

The problem can be seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxZ3G.jpg

How can I make the column be truncated?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 8)` :

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Long":["AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA"],"Somewhat Longer":["AAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAA"], "Really Rather Long":["AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"]})
print("Default")
print(df)
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 8)
print("     ")
print("Colwidth = 8")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Default
   Long Somewhat Longer        Really Rather Long
0  AAAA        AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
1  AAAA        AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2  AAAA        AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
     
Colwidth = 8
   Long Somewhat Longer Really Rather Long
0  AAAA  AAAA...         AAAA...          
1  AAAA  AAAA...         AAAA...          
2  AAAA  AAAA...         AAAA...
```

Comment: hmm, not working for some reason

Comment: Could be an environment issue (ide or whatever is rendering your dataframe), perhaps check data in anothe ide for a.repro?